# JSX syntax for dynamic width of Material UI TextField underline React

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I wanted to add some padding to my TextField component so I applied that to the root 'style' property.

But now the underline isn't staying within that area and is overflowing out to the right by the padding amount. It also seems to ignore any padding left or right I try and apply to it and just goes full 100% width of the container element.

I can fix it's width using the `underlineStyle prop`, so for now I've just set it to 95%, however this can get a bit ugly as the width gets a lot wider. But I can't for the life of me figure out how to express 'width: '100% - 5px' ' in JSX??
Is this possible? I'm sure I just have some syntax wrong.
Thanks in advance

```
<TextField
  inputStyle={styles.inputStyle}
  value={props.messageValue}
  name={props.name}
  onChange={props.handleFieldChange}
  errorText={props.messageError}
  floatingLabelText={props.floatingLabelText}
  underlineStyle={styles.underlineStyle}
  floatingLabelStyle={styles.floatingLabelStyle}
  floatingLabelFocusStyle={styles.floatingLabelFocusStyle}
  **underlineFocusStyle={styles.underlineFocusStyle}**
  style={styles.fieldStyle}
  >
    {props.children}
  </TextField>

underlineFocusStyle: {
borderBottom: 'solid 1px',
borderColor: grey50,
width: '95%'
},
```

Comment: please post your questionable codes.

Comment: OK thanks I've just included the relevant code in order to keep it brief

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`width: 'calc(100% - 5px)'` should work.

Comment: Works great thanks! Just had no clue about the syntax. Thanks again

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!

If your property value is a string it will behave as normal css. As an example: `padding: '5px'` will become `padding: 5px`. But if you put just a number, it will convert it to px's automatically. `padding: 10` becomes `padding: 10px`